Нет реакции на клавишу enter при выполнении функции input()
пытаюсь из скрипта на python (самого простого) создать исполняемый файл (.exe) для запуска его на другом компьютере. Использую pyinstaller, в виртуальном окружении в котором находится скрипт установил pyinstaller, выполнил команду для конвертации в исполняемый файл, все логи отработали, запись об успешном создании, папка dist в ней исполняемый файл, но при попытке его запустить никакой реакции ни на клавишу Enter ни на двойное нажатие. Уже попробовал cx_Freeze, auto-py-to-exe - такая же картина....
Скрипт самый простой - чисто для проверки работоспособности pyinstaller
#***********test.py*************
print('hello, pyinstaller!!!')
input()


Не воспроизводится, а текущих данных не достаточно чтобы вам помочь ‍♀️

Вот логи, которые выходят при сборке файла exe

import os
print('hello, pyinstaller!!!')
os.system("pause")

Вот так будет работать это и в виде файла .py, и в виде автономной сборки. У меня есть, кстати, решения школьных консольных задачек с использованием input(). Их можно превратить в автономные сборки вполне.
Вы взяли настолько простой пример, что он из-за своей простоты оказался нерабочим в данном случае. Как ни смешно это звучит. Использовать input() в роли паузы да ещё в автономной сборке не рекомендую.
